# Percentage transcoded never goes past 65% php-ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg, symfony, ffmpeg-php

### Edit

After some tests it would appear that this bug has something to do directly with the clipped video. If I take 100% of the video, then the percentage transcoded goes up to 100%. If I take only 30% of the video, then the percentage transcoded goes up tot 64-65%.

### Introduction

I'm using https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg for my symfony3 project. Installed via composer.

When the video is done transcoding (when the transcodage percentage reaches 100%) I would like to start another type of operation on the video I just created.

### Problems

However, it would appear that I never get to 100% when I clip a video. It seems to stop at 65% every time.

```
    $format->on('progress', function ($video, $format, $percentage) use ($videoExportPath, $temporary_video_path) {
        //This part never goes past 65%...
        dump("$percentage % transcoded");
        if($percentage == 100) {
            //never enters this part..
            dump("$percentage % transcoded");
            $video = $this->ffmpeg->open($videoExportPath);
            $filterConcat = new ConcatVideoFilter();
            $filterConcat->addFile($temporaryVideoPath);
            dump("second video...");
            $video
                ->addFilter($filterConcat)
                ->save($this->createNewMP4Format(), $videoExportPath);
        }
    });
```

I've looked at the lib to see what is causing this but unfortunately I can not find any indication. The X264 format extends to the DefaultVideo class where the progress listeners are created. Here is the exact function that does that.

```
public function createProgressListener(MediaTypeInterface $media, FFProbe $ffprobe, $pass, $total)
{
    $format = $this;
    $listeners = array(new VideoProgressListener($ffprobe, $media->getPathfile(), $pass, $total));

    foreach ($listeners as $listener) {
        $listener->on('progress', function () use ($format, $media) {
           $format->emit('progress', array_merge(array($media, $format), func_get_args()));
        });
    }

    return $listeners;
}
```

### Questions

And yes the first video I want to create actually gets clipped correctly. Does clipping a video (reducing the length of a video) have something to do with the transcoding percentage to never reach 100%?

Is there a more elegant way to know when a video is done transcoding?

---

https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg/issues/201

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After some tests it would appear that this bug has something to do
>   directly with the clipped video. If I take 100% of the video, then the
>   percentage transcoded goes up to 100%. If I take only 30% of the
>   video, then the percentage transcoded goes up tot 64-65%.

It would appear that I was right about this. To fix this I calculated the percentage difference based on the amount clipped amount.

```
//Where $max is length of the clipped video
//Where $duration is the length of the original video
$temp = ($max*100/$duration);
$percentLimit = (95-ceil($temp));
```

As of right now this seems to work rather well.

```
    if($percentage == $percentLimit) {
        dump("$percentage % transcoded");
        $ffmpegservice->concatWithOutro($videoExportPath, $videoExportPathFinal, $temporaryVideoPath);

    }
```

It's not perfect, but it works.